# How to open web browser with an request object in python

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I have a scenario in which I need to process some the web request automatically and finally show the result in the browser. The website I am querying uses partial response and ajax call to get the whole page.

Is there a way in which I can open a web browser with response object or is there a way in which I can pass data and cookies with the url to web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium` for it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.your-website.com?q=test_param")
# You can sendout a wait to view the results
driver.close()
```

You can very well use chrome driver too if you are very much concerned about the browser